# Apps Script when creating a PDF latest changes aren't there

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, export-to-pdf

I am trying to make a PDF version of a doc that I have just made modifications to in Apps Script. The modifications work fine on the Doc, but when creating the PDF the latest changes are not present.

I've made a dummy version of the code which is producing the error.  Any help would be much appreciated.

```
function createPdf() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.create('Test');
  var body = doc.getBody();
  body.appendParagraph('Test1234');
  var blob = doc.getAs(MimeType.PDF);
  blob.setName('Testpdf');
  DriveApp.createFile(blob);  
}
```

Comment: Did you review the other similar questions before asking this one? It doesn't look like you did

Comment: Based on what evidence? I've spent the last hour looking for solutions to this.

Comment: Thank you.  I couldn't find the correct search terms to find this